# Calling a TRUNCATE and BULK INSERT INTO SQL command from Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am trying to run a simple TRUNCATE and BULK INSERT into SQL from Powershell. Are these commands possible?

```
$server = "TESTING"
$database = "TESTAREA"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=$server;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=$database;")

$query = "TRUNCATE TABLE [TESTAREA].dbo.[client_lookup]"

$query = "BULK INSERT [TESTAREA].dbo.[client_lookup]
FROM '\\fss\share\Accounts\Lookup_Tables\Client_Lookup.csv'
WITH
(
KEEPIDENTITY,
FIRSTROW = 2,
FIELDTERMINATOR= ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'
)"

$connection.Close()
```

Both of these queries execute in SQL and I have used a similar Powershell script to run SQL queries in the past (not BULK INSERT or TRUNCATE). I am fairly new to Powershell, am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a SqlCommand object and execute the script on an open connection.  Refactored example:

```
$server = "TESTING"
$database = "TESTAREA"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=$server;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=$database;")

$query = "TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.client_lookup;
BULK INSERT dbo.client_lookup
FROM '\\fss\share\Accounts\Lookup_Tables\Client_Lookup.csv'
WITH
(
KEEPIDENTITY,
FIRSTROW = 2,
FIELDTERMINATOR= ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'
)";

$connection.Open();
$command = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($query, $connection);
$command.ExecuteNonQuery();
$connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing code that would actually run the query!

Try the Invoke-Sqlcmd cmdlet:

```
$query = "TRUNCATE TABLE [TESTAREA].dbo.[client_lookup];

BULK INSERT [TESTAREA].dbo.[client_lookup]
FROM '\\fss\share\Accounts\Lookup_Tables\Client_Lookup.csv'
WITH
(
KEEPIDENTITY,
FIRSTROW = 2,
FIELDTERMINATOR= ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'
)"

Set-Location SQLSERVER:\SQL\TESTING\\databases\TESTAREA
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query
```

Comment: Frield. Thanks, unfortunately I can't understand what the Set-Location should be pointing at, I've placed my server details there and it just returns the error: Set-Location : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'SQLSERVER' does not exist.

Comment: You need the SQL Server PS snapin: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231683.aspx